# images stopped loading to html page from shared google drive

Tags: html, google-apps-script

the image from the shared folder has stopped loading.

There are 2 images. One on the page, another on favicon, for favicon I wrote apps-script.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return htmlServ.evaluate()
    .setFaviconUrl('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1LZQhGlUfb92QD6Ruh9d6W5fsrrMMumG9#.png')
    .setTitle('CLR: PACKING')
    .addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0")
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>CLR: PACKING</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="conteiner">
    <form novalidate id="my-form">
      <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1L_zI3yyds5Dip72CnTa7C0qDT_KKu6J_" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Last week everything worked. Images loaded on the page and favicon loaded. This morning it stopped to load the images

Comment: the google drive link is 404.. is the image yet present and shared in the drive?

Comment: @ aaandri98 of course yes. Strange al of this...

Comment: try generating again the link from google drive, probably it got corrupted somehow

Comment: @ aaandri98 already I tried that few times. May be you can look what is wrong? for example the image in html page is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_zI3yyds5Dip72CnTa7C0qDT_KKu6J_/view?usp=sharing   this is shared for anyone disk

Comment: @ aaandri98 I found that the permissions were turned off to the shsred folder... thank you for the help! at all it's very strange, because everything worked excellent one week ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is blocked, it asks for authorization in order to view it.. try solving by sharing the link already with the authorization, as suggested in [this answer](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cshare-a-file-publicly) from Google

[image]